# mysql select where where datetime is within this hour

Tags: mysql

Hi I am trying to select row's where the datefiled eg `11-11-2011 12:00` is equal to the current hour.

Sorry, to add it should match the whole date but round to the hour.

Here's what I have so far :

```
SELECT * FROM emails WHERE SUBSTRING(datetosend,0,12) = SUBSTRING(NOW(),0,12)
```

Comment: Is `datetosend` a `char` type or a `date` type?

Comment: What is a string date? This type is not exists in mysql.

Comment: @Jens a date as a string not a date object

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM emails
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datetosend, '%Y-%m-%d %H') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H');
```

This sql doesn't care which date format your column is using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT *
FROM emails
WHERE HOUR(datetosend) = HOUR(NOW());
```

Comment: Updated the question, I want to match the full date.

Comment: What do you mean by round to the hour.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM x where SUBSTRING(d,0,12)=  SUBSTRING(date_format(NOW(), '%d-%m-%Y %I' ),0,12 )
```